# Using type defined in struct as type for function argument inside struct

Tags: c

```
typedef struct flag
  {
           int8_t (*valid)(Flag flag);
    const uint8_t requiresValue;
    const char*   name;
          uint8_t active;
          char*   value;

  } Flag;
```

How do i have the parameter for *valid be Flag inside the struct?

Comment: Use lowercase `flag`, since that's what you used above in the line `typedef struct flag`

Comment: @DillonDavis but then this will not work `flags[i].valid(flags[i])`

Comment: Have you tried it with `(*valid)(flag flags[])` ?

Comment: @DillonDavis https://gyazo.com/22c37ec33168d89149a6bcf89e610729

Comment: @DillonDavis either way it is still a unknown type by the compiler

Comment: You are correct. After some tinkering, I got the following to work `int8_t (*valid)(struct flag* flags);`

Comment: @DillonDavis right, thanks. It works but how do i call the function now?

Comment: @DillonDavis because now the compiler is alright with the struct but `flags[i].valid(flags[i])` does not work

Comment: Isn't `flags[i]` a single Flag, when valid expects a pointer?

Comment: @DillonDavis yeah, i just noticed the error in the post. Now it is correct.

Comment: Due to your edit, the answer you're now looking for is `int8_t (*valid)(struct flag flags);`

Comment: @DillonDavis yeah it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so people can see this is solved.

Comment: @DillonDavis go ahead!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typedef you are looking for is as follows:

```
typedef struct flag
  {
           int8_t (*valid)(struct flag flag);
    const uint8_t requiresValue;
    const char*   name;
          uint8_t active;
          char*   value;

  } Flag;
```

I changed `Flag` to `struct flag`. Note the lowercase `flag` due to the first line `typedef struct flag`.

Comment: You could also use `typedef struct flag Flag; struct flag { int8_t (*valid)(Flag flag); … };`, I believe.